# validating dynamic text box content in PHP

Tags: php

I have this and works fine. But can someone tell me is there a SMARTER way to validate this?

In the validation here, you may find that the `echo "<form.......` is replicated thrice to make sure that the form content is also visible along side the validation message when the form is submitted. Im sure there is a more refined method of validating text box content without form being replicated multiple times.

Also appreciate if some one can suggest me a method to retain the text box value after the form is being submitted. Usually when the form is submitted the value you enter disappears.

Thanks

```
<?php
include ("../connection/index.php"); 
?>
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
</form>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
{
echo "Hello";
echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></form>";

}
if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
{if($_POST['txt1']=='')
{
echo "Hello";
echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></form>";
echo "Empty";}
else
{
echo "Hello";
echo "<form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></form>";
echo "Hit success!";            
}}

?>
```

**EDIT**

Concept

```
  <hard coded submit1 button>
     <dynamically create a text box with a submit2 button>
         <when submit2 is activated is should validate the text box content>
```

When the validation happens both the vaidated message and the text box should be visible

Comment: At the top, you could make sure of the following: **1**: All (or at least one of) of your *expected* $_POST variables exist, and **2**: No *unexpected* one's exist. Do that at the top of your script, then you won't need multiple `isset()` calls further down.

Comment: You could create a session and set each submission values as session values ie. $_SESSION['somevalue']=$_POST['somevalue'];  and if it is set, you can echo it out as value <input type="textfield" value="<php echo $_SESSION['somevalue']; ?>"> or something like that

Comment: Always good to validate on client side with script and then validate php for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
{
    echo "Hello";
}
?>
    <form method='post' action=''>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_POST['sendone'])) {
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
        <?
        } else {
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
            <input type='text' name='txt1' id='txt1'<?=isset($_POST['txt1']) && trim($_POST['txt1']) !== '' ? ' value="'.trim($_POST['txt1']).'"' : ''?>>
            <input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'>
        <?
        }
        ?>
    </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sendtwo'])) {
    if (trim($_POST['txt1']) == '') {
        echo 'Empty';
    } else {
        echo 'Hit success!';
    }
}
```

Comment: pls have a look at the edit.. certain part of the build is hard coded and the balance which needs to be validated in dynamically populated